# GCP storage file.getSignedUrl with write permission and predefined metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I want to let client app upload a file with a specific name, metadata, and, preferably, size. It looks like I can predefine file names on the server-side, but I can't control metadata. Is there way to implement this logic?

[getSignedUrl() API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl)

Answer (score 1):

Some of these use-cases can be solved using policy documents:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document

In node the API is `getSignedPolicy`:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedPolicy

Comment: Yep, i've seen it. Can it specify arbitrary metadata?

Comment: Frankly I have not tested this, but yes, it should work.  A policy document is used to create a POST object upload, described here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-forms .  A POST object upload can contain a number of `x-goog-meta-*` fields, which could be set in the policy form (like any other field).